# Polar vs. ferroelectric point groups

Tags: group-theory, crystals

While both polar and ferroelectric crystals have spontaneous polarizations, only the the ferroelectrics have a reversible polarization. There are 10 polar point groups: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, m, mm2, 3m, 4mm and 6mm (in Hermann–Mauguin notation), and according to every reference I find, the ferroelectric point groups are some smaller subset of this set. However, everyone simply states that the point groups are "some subset" without giving a definitive list.

Are the ferroelectric point groups actually not known? Why can't we precisely state which ones are ferroelectric?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, ferroelectric are indeed a subset of polar (pyroelectric) materials, which comprise the point groups you mentioned.  But all of the point groups you mention have the potential to be ferroelectric, but only some actually are ferroelectric.  As you've pointed out, the literature does not describe specific point groups that are ferroelectric or not ferroelectric.

Therefore, when authors refer to ferroelectrics as a subset of polar materials, it is because of a condition **other** than which point group the ferroelectric is part of.

Ferroelectrics are sometimes described as having "reversible spontaneous polarization".  Spontaneous polarization means they are part of a polar point group (or pyroelectric), but ***reversible*** is an additional requirement that isn't dependent on point groups.